# Selecting from database where boolean field = false

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Im trying to select all records from a database that match todays date and where Boolean called 'collected' is also false

the date is fine its the Boolean im struggling with

Here is my code

```
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire = @todaydate And Where Collected = False"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@todaydate", todaydate)
```

Im unsure of my sql statement and what parameters I should use 
any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to define `Where` once, like so:

```
Select * from Tbl_Rental Where DateOfHire = @todaydate And Collected = False
```

This will solve the issue with the error you're seeing.

Comment: Cheers mate that worked cant upvote you tho im a new user